# Magnetostatics and Newton's third law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, magnetostatics

Here's a simple question that has been driving me to distraction.  Having issues uploading images, so I'm just going to have to describe the system.  Let's say we have a solenoid oriented along the $z$ axis, and it is generating a magnetic field pointing largely in $+\hat{z}$.  We also have a wire sitting a short distance *below* the solenoid, oriented along the $y$ axis, and carrying a current in the $+\hat{y}$ direction.  The solenoid will then produce a $J\times B$ force on the wire pointing in the $+\hat{x}$ direction.

But shouldn't the wire then produce a force on the solenoid in the $-\hat{x}$ direction?  I just can't see how.  At the solenoid location, the field from the wire will point largely in the $+\hat{x}$ direction.  I don't see how there is a $J\times B$ that can resolve to a direction of $-\hat{x}$.  I think I could be convinced that the wire puts a *torque* on the solenoid, but that's not the same thing as an equal and opposite force.  Where is the equal and opposite force?

Comment: I wonder about some of the idealizations sweeping things under the rug. For instance, the wire below the solenoid would have to be narrower than the solenoid, since if it was wider, the return field outside the solenoid  would be closer to the -z direction on the exterior portions of the wire. So, the wire carrying the test current would have to bend out of the way within the radius of the solenoid, and how does that geometry change things? Also, the wire, being so close to the solenoid, would create a magnetic field in nearly the z/-z directions for the portions of the solenoid closest to it.

Comment: @jwimberley  Thinking particularly about your last point.  I don't know that the field from the wire would have to be nearly in z/-z, but it does seem to me that there would indeed be *some* z/-z components that I have neglected, and that might be where the force would come from.  Thinking on it ....

Comment: In general, one can show directly from the Biot-Savart law and the force law that any two current loops do indeed obey Newton's Third Law so long as they are both closed loops.  I *believe* it can be shown to generalize to cases where the current flows "from infinity to infinity" as well, but I would have to go through it to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Exact calculation, except with a missing factor of 2, and a simplified geometry*

For simplicity, imagine a current $I$ travels in the $+\hat y$ direction from a point $(0,-d,0)$ to $(0,d,0)$ within a solenoid of radius $R \gg d$. The current entires and leaves this wire segment from two other wires wire directed parallel to the $\hat z$ axis direction and extending off to negative infinity in the $z$ direction. The solenoid itself extends infinitely in either $\pm \hat z$ direction. Because $R \gg d$, to a good approximation the field on the three straight wires is a constant $B_{solenoid} \hat z$. Furthermore, at the solenoid's scale, the magnetic fields from the two wires parallel to $\hat z$ cancel out. So, the only non-negligible forces are those between the solenoid and the wire of length $2d$ parallel to the $\hat y$-axis.

1. The easy one: the force from the solenoid on the wire parallel is $F=2dIB_{solenoid}$ in the $+\hat x$ direction.
2. The force of the wire on the solenoid can be calculated directly by integrating over the force from each infinitesimal segment of the wire, but because $d \ll R$ these contributions are all nearly equal. So, the Biot-Savart law reduces to
   $$ B_{wire} = \frac{2d\mu_0I}{4 \pi} \frac{\hat y \times r'}{|r'|^3} $$
   The force this field induces on the solenoid can be found by integrating over the cylindrical surface of the solenoid. Ignoring the skew of the looping wires, the solenoid consists of a sheet of current density (in amps/meter) $J$, related to $B_{solenoid}$ by $B_{solenoid} = \mu_0 J$. The force on a loop of the solenoid at height $z$ of width $dz$, carrying current $J\, dz$, is
   $$
   \int_0^{2\pi} (J\, dz) (R\, d \theta) \hat \theta \times B_{wire}
   = \frac{RF\, dz}{4 \pi (z^2+R^2)^{3/2}} \int_0^{2\pi} \hat \theta \times (\hat y \times r') \, d \theta
   $$
   Using some vector triple product identities, and that $r' = (R \cos \theta, R \sin \theta, z)$ and $\hat \theta = (-\sin \theta, \cos \theta, 0)$,
   $$
   \hat \theta \times (\hat y \times r') = \hat y (\hat \theta \cdot r') - r' (\hat \theta \cdot \hat y) = - r' \cos \theta
   $$
   making the integral over $\theta$ above
   $$
   - \int_0^{2\pi} (R \cos^2 \theta, R \sin \theta \cos \theta, z) \, d \theta = -(\pi R,0,2\pi z)
   $$
   and the total expression for the force on the infinitesimal loop
   $$
   - \frac{RF\, dz}{4 (z^2+R^2)^{3/2}} (R,0,2z)
   $$
   The total force is thus the integral of this quantity along the infinite extent of the solenoid. The $\hat y$ and $\hat z$ components components are clearly zero (the latter because the integrand is an odd function). The $\hat x$ component is just
   $$
   - \frac{R^2 F}{4} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(z^2+R^2)^{3/2}} \, dz
   = -\frac{F}{4} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(u^2 + 1)^{3/2}} \, du
   = -\frac{F}{2}
   $$
   Well, that shows the force to be in the $-\hat x$ direction, as required, but there's a factor of two missing somewhere.

Assuming that the missing factor of two isn't emblematic of a bigger problem, the calculation in part 2 above can be repeated for a solenoid that extends only from $z=0$ to $z=\infty$. While the magnetic field generated by the solenoid is no longer the same, the quantity $F$ can be reinterpreted simply as $F \equiv 2d \mu_0 d I J$, and the force on the solenoid is
$$
 - \frac{RF}{4} \int_0^\infty \frac{(R,0,2z)}{(z^2+R^2)^{3/2}} \, dz
=  - \frac{F}{4} \int_0^\infty \frac{(1,0,2u)}{(u^2+1)^{3/2}} \, du
= \left( - \frac{F}{4}, 0, - \frac{F}{2} \right)
$$

Comment: Wow!  DIdn't mean to put you to work!  But thanks.  So it's that small (maybe small) z component after all.  DIdn't think about that.  Maybe I'll go looking for the factor of two someday.  :-)   Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If the wire is located a little below a loop of the solenoid (crossing below its center), then its field will have a (+z) component for negative values of x, and a (-z) component for positive values of x.  The side of the loop on the (-x) side will be pushed in the (-x) direction by the field from the wire, and the one on the (+x) side will also be pushed in the (-x) direction.